# without constructor, is there a way to get child class name in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, class, static, classname

I have a class A and a child class B . now i want to print child class name from a static method of parent class. but both of them doesn't use constructor or new keyword.

```
Class A {
  static run() {
    console.log("child class name");
  }
}

class B extends A {}

B.run();
```

B.run() returning the Class name of B

Comment: put a `static run() {` in `class B`?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure i've really understood your question, let me know if i'm wrong..

You could simply use `this.name` (in the A class) to make B.run returns "B"
As following :

```js
class A {
  static run() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}

class B extends A {}

A.run();
B.run();
```

> `this.name` is available because we're in a static context, in a non-static method you would've use `this.constructor.name` ..